# can't install node-sass for Ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install, node-sass

I'm trying to install node-sass for using with Ionic but it is not possible.

I'm using `nvm` with `node v4.0.0` and `npm 3.8.0` and when I run `sudo npm install -g node-sass` I get this error

```
$ sudo npm install -g node-sass
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@ /home/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass

> node-sass@3.4.2 install /home/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
/home/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Linux 4.1.18-2-MANJARO
npm ERR! argv "/home/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/node" "/home/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "node-sass"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-sass@3.4.2 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.4.2 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/xx/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Could you please help to solve this? it does not work either when using `node v5.0.0`

thanks

Comment: If you are using nvm, you don't need to use sudo. I just tried installing  with `npm install -g node-sass` on my achine and evertyhing worked great. Try running `npm cache clean` if your problem persists

Comment: @FabioAntunes thanks a lot! this solved my problem. I did `npm cache clean` and then installed it without sudo and worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your node version to use node/0.12.10 ... You can use something like n to manage it..

npm install n

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`? In my case this helped.